# Change marker size in plot with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, pandas

I have a geodataframe with points and some associated data. I want to plot it on a map using geopandas and have the size of the points correspond to one of the columns in the geodataframe.

So far I have the following code:

```
base = world.plot(color='white', figsize=(20,10))
geo_df.plot(ax=base, marker='.', color='red', markersize = 
geo_df['Pop_2005'])
plt.xlim([-85, -60])
plt.ylim([-5, 12.5]);
```

But I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: @Fezter that's all the code for drawing the map. There's more code for building the geodataframe but that didn't seem relevant here. Is there anything crucial missing here? Thanks.

Comment: What is the field type of Pop_2005? Is it float or int?

Comment: @Fezter Pop_2005 is of type int, but I have tried it with other fields of type float and I get the same error.

Comment: Could it be that you can only set a single marker size, and it is expecting a single float value and not a series/list/tuple or floats?

Comment: Would it be worth casting `Pop_2005` explicitly to a float or integer? `geo_df['Pop_2005'] = geo_df['Pop_2005'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 19):

In geopandas >= 0.3 (released September 2017), the plotting of points is based on the `scatter` plot method of matplotlib under the hood, and this accepts a variable markersize.

So now you can actually pass a column to `markersize`, what the OP did in the original question:

```
import geopandas

cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
# adding a column with random values for the size
cities['values'] = np.abs(np.random.randn(len(cities))) * 50

cities.plot(markersize=cities['values'])
```

gives:

[image]

Of course, if your goal is simply to change the markersize to a different constant value, you can still pass a single float to the keyword:

```
cities.plot(markersize=10)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the legend represent the marker sizes? Passing legend=True is ignored.